# C# DLL Export to Inno-Setup - Error E0434F4D

Tags: c#, inno-setup, dllexport

I have a C# DLL from which I export a method via RGiesecke.DllExport.

When I call the exported method **from a C# Console Application everything works fine**
but i use it in an **Inno-Setup** and **there i get the following error**:

[image]

The Exported method uses another Method from another DLL.
Strange to me is why i can call a Method from another Class but not from another DLL.
In the Sample below i marked the method that doesn't work.

My question is, why do i get this error ?

**First DLL**

```
namespace ExposeTestLibrary
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DllExport("Test2", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void Test2()
        {
            //works
            TestClass tc = new TestClass();
            tc.DoSomething2();

            //works
            SubLib2 sl2 = new SubLib2();
            sl2.DoSomething3();

            //Doesn't work
            SubLib sl = new SubLib();
            sl.DoSomething();
        }

        public void DoSomething2() 
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("DoSomething2");
        }
    }

    public class SubLib2
    {
        public SubLib2()
        {

        }

        public void DoSomething3()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("DoSomething3");
        }
    }
}
```

**Second DLL**

```
namespace ExposeSubLibrary
{
    public class SubLib
    {
        public SubLib() 
        {

        }

        public void DoSomething() 
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("DoSomething");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how i call it from **Inno-Setup**

```
[Code]
    procedure Test2();
    external 'Test2@{src}\ExposeTestLibrary.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';

function InitializeSetup:boolean;
begin
    MsgBox('WAIT', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
    Test2();
    result:=true;
end;
```

Comment: When faced with an interop problems, programmers think "I know, I'll use [DllExport]".  Now they have two problems.  Your exported method cannot throw *any* exception.  Using try/catch-em-all and *somehow* logging the exception so the caller can retrieve it when you return *false* is a rock-hard requirement.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your comment should state. 1. My method cannot throw any exceptions ? this is true, from any further tests this is something i discovered myself. 2. return false when something fails ? since this is obviously a test and i shrinked it down for the purpose of comprehensibility i think this is irrelevant for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hans is right, you have to think about how to report or log errors.

However, in your case I guess the problem is that the CLR cannot find the other assembly. 
Assemblies are not resolved relative to the assembly that is using them but to the probing path of the current appdomain. 
In your case the appdomain will be the default one and your probing path will be the directory of the executable.

You can setup a handler for AssemblyResolve in the static ctor of TestClass. Or just assembly.load it once with its full filename (also in the static ctor).

Comment: You are a freaking genius :D thanks a lot and greetings to munich